# How to select an option on a website using VBA?

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I have the code below on a website from which I am trying to extract a report. I have managed to navigate to the site a click the relevant buttons to select the report but I have no clue how to select the From date and the Too date. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<select name="dlsPeriodFrom"id="dlsPeriodFrom" class="Items">
    <option selected="selected" value="484">Aug 2017</option>
    <option value="483">Jul 2017</option>
    <option value="482">Jun 2017</option


                <select name="dlsPeriodToo"id="dlsPeriodToo" class="Items">
    <option selected="selected" value="484">Aug 2017</option>
    <option value="483">Jul 2017</option>
    <option value="482">Jun 2017</option
```

Comment: Do you want to read all the options or do you want to set the combo boxes to a specific selection (value)?

Comment: @Noceo I want to set the combo the combo box to say From Jul17 To Jul17. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have the rest of the IE automation in place:

```
document.getElementById("dlsPeriodFrom").value = "483"
document.getElementById("dlsPeriodToo").value = "483"
```

Basically, you have to get the `<select>` element and set it's value to the *value* of the relevant `<option>`

Comment: @Anthony be aware, that some websites changes those values every now and then. So if it is a code with a certain life span, you should make some sort of maintainance plan.